# Select Elements Numerically Dynamic in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just wondering how I can select elements in jQuery dynamically, for example here is a selector of mine:

$("#video_background_video_0, #video_background_video_1, #video_background_video_2, #video_background_video_3, #video_background_video_4").remove();

As you can see this isn't the best example of DRY programming, I'd like to create a selector that selects all elements that begin with `#video_background_video_`. I basically just want to select the above elements in the cleanest way, I was wondering if there is a way that I can dynamically select these elements with some sort of count instead of placing all of my selectors like so, it just looks very messy and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this when it comes to elements with a numeric ending?

As jQuery uses a CSS selector syntax I am unsure how I can do this.

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [start-with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selectors:

```
$('[id^="video_background_video"]').remove();
```

There are other attribute selectors you might be interested [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/),

```
$("[id^='video_background_video'")
```

Also make sure that, this selector is not a native css based one. It will fetch the elements after executing `regular expressions` internally. So it would be better to use it in a minimum level. Its Better to set a common class to those elements and use `class selector` instead.